# Python class import attribute not found

Tags: python, class, memcached

I am new to python and I'm trying to create a very simple API call to a REST service. I need this data in order to import it into another application that only supports python. My issue is that I created a python class and tried to import it into my application. I had several mistakes, and then modified my class file including adding a new function called parse_json. When I run my application now it says that the object has no attribute parse_json. When I run the code directly in the class it works, but running from a separate file and importing the class gives me the error above.

../bin/lib/meetupapi.py -> My class file

```
class MeetupAPI(object):

    BASE_URL = 'https://api.meetup.com'

    def __init__(self, request_uri, api_key, group_urlname):
        self.request_uri = request_uri
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.group_urlname = group_urlname


    # Parse JSON query from API Call
    def parse_json(self, url, result_type=0):
        self.url = url
        self.result_type = result_type

        self.json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
        self.data = json.load(self.json_obj)
        if result_type is not 0:
            if self.data[result_type]:
                return json.dumps(self.data[result_type])
        else:
            return json.dumps(self.data)


    # Get member IDs for profile
    def get_mid(self, request_type):
        self.request_type = request_type

        if self.request_type == 'member':
            self.url = MeetupAPI.BASE_URL + '/2/members?key=' + \
                self.api_key + '&group_urlname=' + self.group_urlname
        elif self.request_type == 'event':
            url = MeetupAPI.BASE_URL + '/2/events?key=' + \
                self.api_key + '&group_urlname=' + self.group_urlname

        self.json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
        self.data = json.load(self.json_obj)
        self.mids = []

        for self.item in self.data['results']:
            if self.item['id']:
                self.mids.extend([self.item['id']])

        return self.mids

    # Get Group IDs for reference
    def get_gid(self):
        self.url = MeetupAPI.BASE_URL + '/' + \
            self.group_urlname + '?key=' + self.api_key

        return self.url

    # Main Meetup API Query for group based information
    def query(self):
        self.url = MeetupAPI.BASE_URL + self.request_uri + '?key=' + \
            self.api_key + '&group_urlname=' + self.group_urlname

        return self.url

    # Get member or event profile information
    def profile(self,mid,gid):
        self.mid = mid
        self.gid = gid

        self.url = MeetupAPI.BASE_URL + '/2/profile/' + \
            str(self.gid) + '/' + \
            str(self.mid) + '?key=' + self.api_key

        return self.url
```

../bin/test.py -> my test file

```
# Import required libraries
from meetupapi import MeetupAPI

Meetup = MeetupAPI(
    '/2/members',
    'xxxxxxx',
    'xxxxxxx'
)
mids = Meetup.get_mid('member')
group = Meetup.get_gid()
gid = Meetup.parse_json(group, 'id')

for mid in mids:
    member = Meetup.profile(mid, gid)
    profile = Meetup.parse_json(member)
    print profile
```

Error when running

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 25, in <module>
    gid = Meetup.parse_json(group, 'id')
AttributeError: 'MeetupAPI' object has no attribute 'parse_json'
```

Please keep in mind that I have never written a class in python before, so I'm probably missing something really easy. I've looked at all the answers provided for others that I could find, but nothing seemed to fit. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the lib directory for meetupapi.pyc (note the "c") and delete it.  Then try importing the module again.  Modules are compiled to bytecode when imported.  If you modify the file a new compile *should* have been done automatically, but perhaps not.

Comment: I don't see a meetupapi.pyc file. I'm I completely doing the import wrong?

Comment: Now that I look at it, your module is in the bin/lib directory.  I wouldn't expect you to be able to import it the way you have.  Is there a meetupapi.py file in your bin directory as well, by chance?

Comment: No...Again, I'm new to this so I read another post that said to create an __init__.py file in the bin directory with:
from lib.meetupapi import MeetupAPI

Comment: Ok...so I moved it into the bin folder and it doesn't get the attribute error anymore. Now I'm just getting a urllib2 not defined error. I added the urllib2 import to the class, but it still has the error. It's also creating the .pyc file.

Comment: Are you doing this in Python 2 or Python 3?  There is no urllib2 in Python3.

Comment: I fixed that part. I'm using python 2.7. I had put the imports in the class for json and urllib2. Once I moved them to the top of the file, before the class, everything started working like its supposed to. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: No problem.  As a rule, I try to keep imports at the top of the module.  This way I can avoid calling an imported resource before I've actually done the import.  Not sure if that was your issue, but it's a good thing to consider.